# error connecting to mongodb due to {useNewUrlParser:boolean, useUnifiedTopology:boolean} is not assignable to parameter of type 'Callback<MongoClient>

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Below is the code I am using to connect to mongodb.

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb"

const user = 'user_001'
const userPassword = '<password>'
const cluster = 'cluster0.1jjgj'

const url = `mongodb+srv://${user}:${userPassword}@${cluster}.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

export const connectDatabase = async() => {
  
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });

  const db = client.db('main')

  return {
    listings: db.collection('test-listings')
  }
}
```

Tried connecting mongodb with MongoDB NodeJS Driver `mongodb` but following error occurs.
what does MongoClientOptions (useNewUrlParser: boolean, useUnifiedTopology:boolean) do in mongodb and what could be causing this error ? please explain. Thank you.

```
  Overload 1 of 4, '(url: string, callback: Callback<MongoClient>): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ useNewUrlParser: boolean; useUnifiedTopology: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Callback<MongoClient>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'useNewUrlParser' does not exist in type 'Callback<MongoClient>'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(url: string, options: MongoClientOptions): Promise<MongoClient>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ useNewUrlParser: boolean; useUnifiedTopology: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MongoClientOptions'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'useNewUrlParser' does not exist in type 'MongoClientOptions'.ts(2769)
```

exporting connectDatabase in the below file (index.ts).

```
import express, {Application} from "express";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import { typeDefs, resolvers } from "./graphql/index";
import { connectDatabase } from "./database";

const port = 3000;

const mount = async (app: Application) => {

  const db = await connectDatabase();

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs, 
    resolvers, 
    context:() => ({ db })
  });

  server.applyMiddleware({app, path:'/api'})
  
  app.listen(port);
  
  console.log(`[app]: http://localhost:${port}`);

  const listings = await db.listings.find({}).toArray();
  console.log(listings);
  
}

mount(express());
```

Comment: The connection with the `useUnifiedTopology` and `useNewUrlParser` options doesn't work for me either. Can't say for sure, but they seem to be removed from last versions of the MongoDB NodeJS Driver. Just try to remove these options

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect to the client with:

```
export const connectDatabase = async () => {
    const client = new MongoClient(url);
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db('main');
  
    return {
      listings: db.collection('test-listings'),
    };
  };
```

Comment: But it return an empty array even though there is a document in test-listings collection for const listings = await db.listings.find({}).toArray();`

Comment: Can you post the code where you are executing the query?

Comment: code: https://gist.github.com/kkratos/0a97521bc95dfb5dcb986f0f40df9b8b

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine, Emphasis on poolSize.

```
mongoose.connect(
dbUrl,
{
useNewUrlParser: true,
useCreateIndex: true,
autoIndex: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
poolSize: 10,
},
function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`Unable to Connect to Database. ${err.name} ${err.message}`);
    process.exit(1);
   } else {
    console.log(new Date());
    console.error("Successfully connected to Database");
   }
  }
);
```

for more info check https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/argument-of-type-usenewurlparser-boolean-useunifiedtopology-boolean-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type/119731/4

Comment: The question was not about using mongoose. And it seems that mongoose is not the best choice anymore: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/article/mongoose-versus-nodejs-driver/